# ContainerCreating: Error from server (BadRequest): container "kubedns"

Tags: kubernetes

I have setup this 3 nodes cluster (http://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/vagrant/).

after restarting my nodes. KubeDNS service is not starting. log didn't show much information.

getting bellow message

```
$  kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system kube-dns-v19-sqx9q -c kubedns
Error from server (BadRequest): container "kubedns" in pod "kube-dns-v19-sqx9q" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating
```

nodes are running.

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME            STATUS                     AGE       VERSION
172.18.18.101   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   2d        v1.6.0
172.18.18.102   Ready                      2d        v1.6.0
172.18.18.103   Ready                      2d        v1.6.0


$ kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                        READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
calico-node-6rhb9                           2/2       Running             4          2d
calico-node-mbhk7                           2/2       Running             93         2d
calico-node-w9sjq                           2/2       Running             6          2d
calico-policy-controller-2425378810-rd9h7   1/1       Running             0          25m
kube-dns-v19-sqx9q                          0/3       ContainerCreating   0          25m
kubernetes-dashboard-2457468166-rs0tn       0/1       ContainerCreating   0          25m
```

How can I find what is wrong with DNS service?

Thanks
SR

**some more details**

```
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubObjectPath   Type        Reason      Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------      -------
  31m       31m     1   kubelet, 172.18.18.102          Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "d7c71007-2933-11e7-9bbd-08002774bad8" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = 2 desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod \"_\" network: CNI failed to retrieve network namespace path: Error: No such container: 87bd5c4bc5b9d81468170cc840ba9203988bb259aa0c025372ee02303d9e8d4b"

  31m   31m 1   kubelet, 172.18.18.102      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "d7c71007-2933-11e7-9bbd-08002774bad8" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = 2 desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod \"_\" network: CNI failed to retrieve network namespace path: Error: No such container: d091593b55eb9e16e09c5bc47f4701015839d83d23546c4c6adc070bc37ad60d"

  30m   30m 1   kubelet, 172.18.18.102      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: No such container: 69a1fa33f26b851664b2ad10def1eb37b5e5391ca33dad2551a2f98c52e05d0d
  30m   30m 1   kubelet, 172.18.18.102      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "d7c71007-2933-11e7-9bbd-08002774bad8" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = 2 desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod \"_\" network: CNI failed to retrieve network namespace path: Error: No such container: c3b7c06df3bea90e4d12c0b7f1a03077edf5836407206038223967488b279d3d"

  28m   28m 1   kubelet, 172.18.18.102      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "d7c71007-2933-11e7-9bbd-08002774bad8" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = 2 desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod \"_\" network: CNI failed to retrieve network namespace path: Error: No such container: 467d54496eb5665c5c7c20b1adb0cc0f01987a83901e4b54c1dc9ccb4860f16d"

  28m   28m 1   kubelet, 172.18.18.102      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: No such container: 1cd8022c9309205e61d7e593bc7ff3248af17d731e2a4d55e74b488cbc115162
  27m   27m 1   kubelet, 172.18.18.102      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: No such container: 1ed4174aba86124055981b7888c9d048d784e98cef5f2763fd1352532a0ba85d
  26m   26m 1   kubelet, 172.18.18.102      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "d7c71007-2933-11e7-9bbd-08002774bad8" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = 2 desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod \"_\" network: CNI failed to retrieve network namespace path: Error: No such container: 444693b4ce06eb25f3dbd00aebef922b72b291598fec11083cb233a0f9d5e92d"

  25m   25m 1   kubelet, 172.18.18.102      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: No such container: 736df24a9a6640300d62d542e5098e03a5a9fde4f361926e2672880b43384516
  8m    8m  1   kubelet, 172.18.18.102      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: No such container: 8424dbdf92b16602c7d5a4f61d21cd602c5da449c6ec3449dafbff80ff5e72c4
  2h    1m  49  kubelet, 172.18.18.102      Warning FailedSync  (events with common reason combined)
  2h    2s  361 kubelet, 172.18.18.102      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for "kube-dns-v19-sqx9q_kube-system(d7c71007-2933-11e7-9bbd-08002774bad8)" with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"kube-dns-v19-sqx9q_kube-system(d7c71007-2933-11e7-9bbd-08002774bad8)\" failed: rpc error: code = 2 desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod \"kube-dns-v19-sqx9q_kube-system\" network: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get pods kube-dns-v19-sqx9q)"

  2h    1s  406 kubelet, 172.18.18.102      Normal  SandboxChanged  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
```

**pod describe output**

```
Name:       kube-dns-v19-sqx9q
Namespace:  kube-system
Node:       172.18.18.102/172.18.18.102
Start Time: Mon, 24 Apr 2017 17:34:22 -0400
Labels:     k8s-app=kube-dns
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true
        version=v19
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicationController","namespace":"kube-system","name":"kube-dns-v19","uid":"dac3d892-278c-11e7-b2b5-0800...
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod=
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerations=[{"key":"CriticalAddonsOnly", "operator":"Exists"}]
Status:     Pending
IP:     
Controllers:    ReplicationController/kube-dns-v19
Containers:
  kubedns:
    Container ID:   
    Image:      gcr.io/google_containers/kubedns-amd64:1.7
    Image ID:       
    Ports:      10053/UDP, 10053/TCP
    Args:
      --domain=cluster.local
      --dns-port=10053
    State:      Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:      False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:  100m
      memory:   170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:       70Mi
    Liveness:       http-get http://:8080/healthz delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:      http-get http://:8081/readiness delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-r5xws (ro)
  dnsmasq:
    Container ID:   
    Image:      gcr.io/google_containers/kube-dnsmasq-amd64:1.3
    Image ID:       
    Ports:      53/UDP, 53/TCP
    Args:
      --cache-size=1000
      --no-resolv
      --server=127.0.0.1#10053
    State:      Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:      False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-r5xws (ro)
  healthz:
    Container ID:   
    Image:      gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz-amd64:1.1
    Image ID:       
    Port:       8080/TCP
    Args:
      -cmd=nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1 >/dev/null && nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1:10053 >/dev/null
      -port=8080
      -quiet
    State:      Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:      False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:  10m
      memory:   50Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      10m
      memory:       50Mi
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-r5xws (ro)
Conditions:
  Type      Status
  Initialized   True 
  Ready     False 
  PodScheduled  True 
Volumes:
  default-token-r5xws:
    Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-r5xws
    Optional:   false
QoS Class:  Burstable
Node-Selectors: <none>
Tolerations:    <none>
```

Comment: `the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get pods kube-dns-v19-sqx9q)` is your hint...

Comment: I deleted and created the dns pods. looks like one of the node not able mount the file system. kubelet, 172.18.18.103                  Warning         FailedMount     MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "kubernetes.io/secret/32a98bf6-2a1d-11e7-b43a-08002774bad8-default-token-r5xws" (spec.Name: "default-token-r5xws") pod "32a98bf6-2a1d-11e7-b43a-08002774bad8" (UID: "32a98bf6-2a1d-11e7-b43a-08002774bad8") with: secrets "default-token-r5xws" not found

Comment: Looks like the bootstrap of your cluster is broken: Search in the logs for the secret creation. It should be created in the kube system namespace.

Answer (score 1):

service account mount  `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount` from  secret `default-token-r5xws` failed. Check the logs for this secret creation failure.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by signing-in to my Docker Desktop that is running on my computer.

(I was running Kubernetes on my computer via minikube)